# Custom arrayadapter showing duplicates only when scrolling fast

Tags: android, android-listview, android-asynctask, android-arrayadapter

I got my listview working almost good enough. When I scroll fast up OR down it shows the same 3-4 pictures every time, which slowly turn into the right image.

Code to retrieve bitmap that I think needs fixing

```
public Bitmap retrieveBitmap(String url) throws Exception {
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        try {
            inputStream = this.retrieveStream(url);
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 8;
            final Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream, null, options);
            return bitmap;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (inputStream != null) {
                    inputStream.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Before I added the options sample size it kept crashing as I scrolled, I just copied this off another stack question but am not sure what exactly it is doing besides reducing the size somehow.

Adapter class

```
package com.example.jdmb;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MoviesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movies> {
    private ArrayList<Movies> movieData;
    private Activity context;

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<Movies> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = (Activity) context;
        this.movieData = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieId);
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
            holder.vote_avg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieAvg);
            holder.backdrop_path = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.movieBackdrop);
            holder.release_date = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.movieRelease);
            holder.original_title = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.movieTitle2);
            holder.vote_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieCount);
            holder.adult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieAdult);
            holder.poster = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.moviePoster);
            holder.popularity = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.moviePopularity);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }
        Movies movie = movieData.get(position);

        if (movie != null) {
            // check to see if each individual textview is null.
            // if not, assign some text!

            holder.id.setText("id: " + movie.getId());
            holder.title.setText("title: " + movie.getTitle());
            holder.vote_avg.setText("vote_avg: " + movie.getVote_average());
            DownloadBitmap.downloadBitmap(holder.backdrop_path,
                    movie.getBackdrop_path());
            holder.release_date.setText("release_date: "
                    + movie.getRelease_date());
            holder.original_title.setText("original_title: "
                    + movie.getOriginal_title());
            holder.vote_count.setText("vote_count: " + movie.getVote_count());
            holder.adult.setText("adult: " + movie.isAdult());
            DownloadBitmap
                    .downloadBitmap(holder.poster, movie.getPoster_path());
            holder.popularity.setText("popularity: " + movie.getPopularity());

        }
        return view;

    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView id;
        TextView title;
        TextView vote_avg;
        ImageView backdrop_path;
        TextView release_date;
        TextView original_title;
        TextView vote_count;
        TextView adult;
        ImageView poster;
        TextView popularity;
    }
}
```

Downloader class

```
package com.example.jdmb;

import java.io.InputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory.Options;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DownloadBitmap {
    static Bitmap image;

    public static void downloadBitmap(final ImageView imageView,
            final String url) {

        new AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap>() {

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
                HttpRetriever retriever = new HttpRetriever();
                try {                   
                    image = retriever.retrieveBitmap(url);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
                return image;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                if (imageView != null) {

                    imageView.setImageBitmap(result);
                }
            }

        }.execute();

    }
}
```

What part of my code is making me see the same photos when scrolling, I think it has something to do with recycling the images, but not sure how to get past it.

Comment: This happens because the ImageView bitmap is not set until download completes.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide a more robust solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recycled ImageView shows that last bitmap you told it to. You either need to set the holder.backdrop_path & holder.poster to a generic resource before returning the view or in onPreExecute of your AsyncTask.

Like this:

```
package com.example.jdmb;

import java.io.InputStream;

import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class DownloadBitmap {
    static Bitmap image;

    public static void downloadBitmap(final ImageView imageView,
            final String url) {

        new AsyncTask<Bitmap, Void, Bitmap>() {

            protected void onPreExecute(){
                //This could also be an internal resource instead of null
                imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
            }

            @Override
            protected Bitmap doInBackground(Bitmap... params) {
                HttpRetriever retriever = new HttpRetriever();
                InputStream is = retriever.retrieveStream(url);
                image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
                return image;

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(result);

            }

        }.execute();

    }
}
```

I would recommend a much more robust way of accomplishing this task. This solution will require you to use the [Volley Library](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/) and the majority of this code can be found in the [Google IO source](https://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/checkout). [Here](https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728) is a video covering the same topic if it helps.

Download Volley and add it to your build path.
We are going to uses the Google IO super class of the Volley ImageLoader.

```
*
 * Copyright 2012 Google Inc.
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.android.apps.iosched.util;

import android.animation.Animator;
import android.animation.AnimatorListenerAdapter;
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.TransitionDrawable;
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.android.volley.Cache;
import com.android.volley.Network;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.DiskBasedCache;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpClientStack;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * A class that wraps up remote image loading requests using the Volley library combined with a
 * memory cache. An single instance of this class should be created once when your Activity or
 * Fragment is created, then use {@link #get(String, android.widget.ImageView)} or one of
 * the variations to queue the image to be fetched and loaded from the network. Loading images
 * in a {@link android.widget.ListView} or {@link android.widget.GridView} is also supported but
 * you must store the {@link com.android.volley.Request} in your ViewHolder type class and pass it
 * into loadImage to ensure the request is canceled as views are recycled.
 */
public class ImageLoader extends com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader {
    private static final ColorDrawable transparentDrawable = new ColorDrawable(
            android.R.color.transparent);
    private static final int HALF_FADE_IN_TIME = UIUtils.ANIMATION_FADE_IN_TIME / 2;
    private static final String CACHE_DIR = "images";

    private Resources mResources;
    private ArrayList<Drawable> mPlaceHolderDrawables;
    private boolean mFadeInImage = true;
    private int mMaxImageHeight = 0;
    private int mMaxImageWidth = 0;

    /**
     * Creates an ImageLoader with Bitmap memory cache. No default placeholder image will be shown
     * while the image is being fetched and loaded.
     */
    public ImageLoader(FragmentActivity activity) {
        super(newRequestQueue(activity),
                BitmapCache.getInstance(activity.getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mResources = activity.getResources();
    }

    /**
     * Creates an ImageLoader with Bitmap memory cache and a default placeholder image while the
     * image is being fetched and loaded.
     */
    public ImageLoader(FragmentActivity activity, int defaultPlaceHolderResId) {
        super(newRequestQueue(activity),
                BitmapCache.getInstance(activity.getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mResources = activity.getResources();
        mPlaceHolderDrawables = new ArrayList<Drawable>(1);
        mPlaceHolderDrawables.add(defaultPlaceHolderResId == -1 ?
                null : mResources.getDrawable(defaultPlaceHolderResId));
    }

    /**
     * Creates an ImageLoader with Bitmap memory cache and a list of default placeholder drawables.
     */
    public ImageLoader(FragmentActivity activity, ArrayList<Drawable> placeHolderDrawables) {
        super(newRequestQueue(activity),
                BitmapCache.getInstance(activity.getSupportFragmentManager()));
        mResources = activity.getResources();
        mPlaceHolderDrawables = placeHolderDrawables;
    }

    /**
     * Starts processing requests on the {@link RequestQueue}.
     */
    public void startProcessingQueue() {
        getRequestQueue().start();
    }

    /**
     * Stops processing requests on the {@link RequestQueue}.
     */
    public void stopProcessingQueue() {
        getRequestQueue().stop();
    }

    public ImageLoader setFadeInImage(boolean fadeInImage) {
        mFadeInImage = fadeInImage;
        return this;
    }

    public ImageLoader setMaxImageSize(int maxImageWidth, int maxImageHeight) {
        mMaxImageWidth = maxImageWidth;
        mMaxImageHeight = maxImageHeight;
        return this;
    }

    public ImageLoader setMaxImageSize(int maxImageSize) {
        return setMaxImageSize(maxImageSize, maxImageSize);
    }

    public ImageContainer get(String requestUrl, ImageView imageView) {
        return get(requestUrl, imageView, 0);
    }

    public ImageContainer get(String requestUrl, ImageView imageView, int placeHolderIndex) {
        return get(requestUrl, imageView, mPlaceHolderDrawables.get(placeHolderIndex),
                mMaxImageWidth, mMaxImageHeight);
    }

    public ImageContainer get(String requestUrl, ImageView imageView, Drawable placeHolder) {
        return get(requestUrl, imageView, placeHolder, mMaxImageWidth, mMaxImageHeight);
    }

    public ImageContainer get(String requestUrl, ImageView imageView, Drawable placeHolder,
            int maxWidth, int maxHeight) {

        // Find any old image load request pending on this ImageView (in case this view was
        // recycled)
        ImageContainer imageContainer = imageView.getTag() != null &&
                imageView.getTag() instanceof ImageContainer ?
                (ImageContainer) imageView.getTag() : null;

        // Find image url from prior request
        String recycledImageUrl = imageContainer != null ? imageContainer.getRequestUrl() : null;

        // If the new requestUrl is null or the new requestUrl is different to the previous
        // recycled requestUrl
        if (requestUrl == null || !requestUrl.equals(recycledImageUrl)) {
            if (imageContainer != null) {
                // Cancel previous image request
                imageContainer.cancelRequest();
                imageView.setTag(null);
            }
            if (requestUrl != null) {
                // Queue new request to fetch image
                imageContainer = get(requestUrl,
                        getImageListener(mResources, imageView, placeHolder, mFadeInImage),
                        maxWidth, maxHeight);
                // Store request in ImageView tag
                imageView.setTag(imageContainer);
            } else {
                imageView.setImageDrawable(placeHolder);
                imageView.setTag(null);
            }
        }

        return imageContainer;
    }

    private static ImageListener getImageListener(final Resources resources,
            final ImageView imageView, final Drawable placeHolder, final boolean fadeInImage) {
        return new ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                imageView.setTag(null);
                if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                    setImageBitmap(imageView, response.getBitmap(), resources,
                            fadeInImage && !isImmediate);
                } else {
                    imageView.setImageDrawable(placeHolder);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
            }
        };
    }

    private static RequestQueue newRequestQueue(Context context) {

        // On HC+ use HurlStack which is based on HttpURLConnection. Otherwise fall back on
        // AndroidHttpClient (based on Apache DefaultHttpClient) which should no longer be used
        // on newer platform versions where HttpURLConnection is simply better.
        Network network = new BasicNetwork(
                UIUtils.hasHoneycomb() ?
                        new HurlStack() :
                        new HttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(
                                NetUtils.getUserAgent(context))));

        Cache cache = new DiskBasedCache(getDiskCacheDir(context, CACHE_DIR));
        RequestQueue queue = new RequestQueue(cache, network);
        queue.start();
        return queue;
    }

    /**
     * Sets a {@link android.graphics.Bitmap} to an {@link android.widget.ImageView} using a
     * fade-in animation. If there is a {@link android.graphics.drawable.Drawable} already set on
     * the ImageView then use that as the image to fade from. Otherwise fade in from a transparent
     * Drawable.
     */
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR1)
    private static void setImageBitmap(final ImageView imageView, final Bitmap bitmap,
            Resources resources, boolean fadeIn) {

        // If we're fading in and on HC MR1+
        if (fadeIn && UIUtils.hasHoneycombMR1()) {
            // Use ViewPropertyAnimator to run a simple fade in + fade out animation to update the
            // ImageView
            imageView.animate()
                    .scaleY(0.95f)
                    .scaleX(0.95f)
                    .alpha(0f)
                    .setDuration(imageView.getDrawable() == null ? 0 : HALF_FADE_IN_TIME)
                    .setListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
                        @Override
                        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            imageView.animate()
                                    .alpha(1f)
                                    .scaleY(1f)
                                    .scaleX(1f)
                                    .setDuration(HALF_FADE_IN_TIME)
                                    .setListener(null);
                        }
                    });
        } else if (fadeIn) {
            // Otherwise use a TransitionDrawable to fade in
            Drawable initialDrawable;
            if (imageView.getDrawable() != null) {
                initialDrawable = imageView.getDrawable();
            } else {
                initialDrawable = transparentDrawable;
            }
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(resources, bitmap);
            // Use TransitionDrawable to fade in
            final TransitionDrawable td =
                    new TransitionDrawable(new Drawable[] {
                            initialDrawable,
                            bitmapDrawable
                    });
            imageView.setImageDrawable(td);
            td.startTransition(UIUtils.ANIMATION_FADE_IN_TIME);
        } else {
            // No fade in, just set bitmap directly
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Get a usable cache directory (external if available, internal otherwise).
     *
     * @param context The context to use
     * @param uniqueName A unique directory name to append to the cache dir
     * @return The cache dir
     */
    public static File getDiskCacheDir(Context context, String uniqueName) {
        // Check if media is mounted or storage is built-in, if so, try and use external cache dir
        // otherwise use internal cache dir

        // TODO: getCacheDir() should be moved to a background thread as it attempts to create the
        // directory if it does not exist (no disk access should happen on the main/UI thread).
        final String cachePath =
                Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(Environment.getExternalStorageState()) ||
                        !Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()
                        ? getExternalCacheDir(context).getPath()
                        : context.getCacheDir().getPath();

        return new File(cachePath + File.separator + uniqueName);
    }

    /**
     * Get the external app cache directory.
     *
     * @param context The context to use
     * @return The external cache dir
     */
    private static File getExternalCacheDir(Context context) {
        // TODO: This needs to be moved to a background thread to ensure no disk access on the
        // main/UI thread as unfortunately getExternalCacheDir() calls mkdirs() for us (even
        // though the Volley library will later try and call mkdirs() as well from a background
        // thread).
        return context.getExternalCacheDir();
    }

    /**
     * Interface an activity can implement to provide an ImageLoader to its children fragments.
     */
    public interface ImageLoaderProvider {
        public ImageLoader getImageLoaderInstance();
    }

}
```

Now in your Activity Create the ImageLoader and pass it to you adapter when you create your adapter.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
...
ImageLoader mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this, R.drawable.default_image);
MoviesAdapter  mMoviesAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(this, R.layout.your_list_layout, moviesList, mImageLoader);
...
}
```

Adjust your Movie Adapter constructor.

```
package com.example.jdmb;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MoviesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Movies> {
    private ArrayList<Movies> movieData;
    private Activity context;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;

    public MoviesAdapter(Context context, int resource,
            ArrayList<Movies> objects, ImageLoader loader) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.context = (Activity) context;
        this.movieData = objects;
        this.mImageLoader = loader;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = vi.inflate(R.layout.list_row, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.id = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieId);
            holder.title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieTitle);
            holder.vote_avg = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieAvg);
            holder.backdrop_path = (ImageView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.movieBackdrop);
            holder.release_date = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.movieRelease);
            holder.original_title = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.movieTitle2);
            holder.vote_count = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieCount);
            holder.adult = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.movieAdult);
            holder.poster = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.moviePoster);
            holder.popularity = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.moviePopularity);
            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        }
        Movies movie = movieData.get(position);

        if (movie != null) {
            // check to see if each individual textview is null.
            // if not, assign some text!

            holder.id.setText("id: " + movie.getId());
            holder.title.setText("title: " + movie.getTitle());
            holder.vote_avg.setText("vote_avg: " + movie.getVote_average());
            mImageLoader.get(movie.getBackdrop_path(), holder.backdrop_path);
            holder.release_date.setText("release_date: "
                    + movie.getRelease_date());
            holder.original_title.setText("original_title: "
                    + movie.getOriginal_title());
            holder.vote_count.setText("vote_count: " + movie.getVote_count());
            holder.adult.setText("adult: " + movie.isAdult());
            mImageLoader.get(movie.getPoster_path(), holder.poster);
            holder.popularity.setText("popularity: " + movie.getPopularity());
        }
        return view;
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView id;
        TextView title;
        TextView vote_avg;
        ImageView backdrop_path;
        TextView release_date;
        TextView original_title;
        TextView vote_count;
        TextView adult;
        ImageView poster;
        TextView popularity;
    }
}
```

I may have missed something or made typing mistakes as I did not directly test this but I am using a similar implementation in one of my own apps.

Comment: This is giving me weird behavior, besides just crashing with "cannot allocate too large" error. At first it looks like there are no duplicates, but when I scroll back up the views get blank and begin to get laggy and crash if I scroll too fast. I imagine this is because when I scroll up it calls getview and sets the image to blank before it loads? or something..I feel like I am approaching this wrong

Comment: I would probably approach this differently but I was trying to provide a quick solution using your current code to avoid duplicates. Consider the number of tasks you are creating as you scroll. All of them are trying to simultaneously download images and then set them when the download finished regardless of if the view is visible.

Comment: Consider using Volley? Spcifically the ImageLoader. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master

Comment: I realized that my app is no longer showing duplicates but is still crashing due to memory problems. If I scroll slowly its fine, but if i scroll fast it force closes..I updated OP with error log

Comment: So you are loading to many images into memory and they are not being garbage collected fast enough so your app crashes because it exceeds its allotted memory.

Comment: If that is the case, how do people make programs that do nothing but load galleries? what do I do to prevent this. I can't believe how much there is to arrayadapters, took long enough just getting the list to show something now its showing too much.

Comment: So this is not something I can easily explain in a comment. That said  you need to consider whats happening when you are loading a lot of images, when you fling your finger down this list you could potentially start loading 25+ images at the same time but you really only need to download the visible image views. Then you fling up the list and start downloading the same images again with the same issue you had when you scrolled down. You need to develop a solution that caches images and doesn't start or cancels downloading images that the user isn't looking at. I will update my answer...